# Reinstall Visual Studio and retain all settings?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have Visual Studio 2012 installed on the C:\ drive. I am running out of space and would like to uninstall, then reinstall it to another drive. Is there a way I can do this and retain all my configurations, extensions, TFS settings, etc?

Comment: This almost belongs more on Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export all of your settings, reinstall Visual Studio, and then import your exported settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zbhkx167.aspx